# Transposing 8x8 float matrix using NEON intrinsics

Tags: c, transpose, intrinsics, neon

I have a program that needs to run a transpose operation on 8x8 float32 matrices many times. I want to transpose these using NEON SIMD intrinsics. I know that the array will always contain 8x8 float elements. I have a baseline non-intrinsic solution below:

```
void transpose(float *matrix, float *matrixT) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
            matrixT[i*8+j] = matrix[j*8+i];
        }
    }
}
```

I also created an intrinsic solution that transposes each 4x4 quadrant of the 8x8 matrix, and swaps the positions of the second and third quadrants. This solution looks like this:

```
void transpose_4x4(float *matrix, float *matrixT, int store_index) {
    float32x4_t r0, r1, r2, r3, c0, c1, c2, c3;
    r0 = vld1q_f32(matrix);
    r1 = vld1q_f32(matrix + 8);
    r2 = vld1q_f32(matrix + 16);
    r3 = vld1q_f32(matrix + 24);

    c0 = vzip1q_f32(r0, r1);
    c1 = vzip2q_f32(r0, r1);
    c2 = vzip1q_f32(r2, r3);
    c3 = vzip2q_f32(r2, r3);

    r0 = vcombine_f32(vget_low_f32(c0), vget_low_f32(c2));
    r1 = vcombine_f32(vget_high_f32(c0), vget_high_f32(c2));
    r2 = vcombine_f32(vget_low_f32(c1), vget_low_f32(c3));
    r3 = vcombine_f32(vget_high_f32(c1), vget_high_f32(c3));

    vst1q_f32(matrixT + store_index, r0);
    vst1q_f32(matrixT + store_index + 8, r1);
    vst1q_f32(matrixT + store_index + 16, r2);
    vst1q_f32(matrixT + store_index + 24, r3);
}

void transpose(float *matrix, float *matrixT) {
    // Transpose top-left 4x4 quadrant and store the result in the top-left 4x4 quadrant
    transpose_4x4(matrix, matrixT, 0);

    // Transpose top-right 4x4 quadrant and store the result in the bottom-left 4x4 quadrant
    transpose_4x4(matrix + 4, matrixT, 32);

    // Transpose bottom-left 4x4 quadrant and store the result in the top-right 4x4 quadrant
    transpose_4x4(matrix + 32, matrixT, 4);

    // Transpose bottom-right 4x4 quadrant and store the result in the bottom-right 4x4 quadrant
    transpose_4x4(matrix + 36, matrixT, 36);
}
```

This solution however, results in a slower performance than the baseline non-intrinsic solution. I am struggling to see, if there is one, a faster solution that can transpose my 8x8 matrix. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Edit: both solutions are compiled using the -O1 flag.

Comment: It might be a good idea to include some extra details, like which ARM ISA you're building for, and what compiler options you're using.

Comment: *both solutions are compiled using the -O1 flag.* Why not full optimization?  Use at least `-O2` to enable function inlining!!  Preferably `-O3 -mcpu=cortex-a76` or whatever matches your target machine.

Comment: Performance alert: there is no single (free) toolchain that does permutations such as `vtrn` `vzip`, and `vuzp` properly without bloating the binary with useless `vmov` and `vorr` for arm32. You should better write it in assembly.

Comment: You picked the wrong intrinsic in `vzip`. you should use `vtrn` exclusively since it's a `transpose` problem.

Answer (score 5):

First off, you shouldn't expect a huge performance boost to start with:

- there is actually no computation
- you are dealing with 32bit data, and thus, not much of bandwidth constraint.

to sum it up, just a little bit saving in bandwidth by vectorizing - that's all

As for the 4x4 transpose, you don't even need a separate function, but just a macro:

```
#define TRANSPOSE4x4(pSrc,pDst) vst1q_f32_x4(pDst,vld4q_f32(pSrc))
```

will do the job since NEON does the 4x4 transpose on the fly when you load the data with `vld4`.

But you should ask yourself at this point if your approach - transposing all the matrice prior to actual computation - is the right one if 4x4 transpose costs virtually nothing. This step could end up being a pure waste of computation and bandwidth. Optimization shouldn't be limited to the final step, but should be considered from the designing phase.

8x8 transpose is a different animal though:

```
void transpose8x8(float *pDst, float *pSrc)
    {
        float32x4_t row0a, row0b, row1a, row1b, row2a, row2b, row3a, row3b, row4a, row4b, row5a, row5b, row6a, row6b, row7a, row7b;
        float32x4_t r0a, r0b, r1a, r1b, r2a, r2b, r3a, r3b, r4a, r4b, r5a, r5b, r6a, r6b, r7a, r7b;

        row0a = vld1q_f32(pSrc);
        pSrc += 4;
        row0b = vld1q_f32(pSrc);
        pSrc += 4;
        row1a = vld1q_f32(pSrc);
        pSrc += 4;
        row1b = vld1q_f32(pSrc);
        pSrc += 4;
        row2a = vld1q_f32(pSrc);
        pSrc += 4;
        row2b = vld1q_f32(pSrc);
        pSrc += 4;
        row3a = vld1q_f32(pSrc);
        pSrc += 4;
        row3b = vld1q_f32(pSrc);
        pSrc += 4;
        row4a = vld1q_f32(pSrc);
        pSrc += 4;
        row4b = vld1q_f32(pSrc);
        pSrc += 4;
        row5a = vld1q_f32(pSrc);
        pSrc += 4;
        row5b = vld1q_f32(pSrc);
        pSrc += 4;
        row6a = vld1q_f32(pSrc);
        pSrc += 4;
        row6b = vld1q_f32(pSrc);
        pSrc += 4;
        row7a = vld1q_f32(pSrc);
        pSrc += 4;
        row7b = vld1q_f32(pSrc);

        r0a = vtrn1q_f32(row0a, row1a);
        r0b = vtrn1q_f32(row0b, row1b);
        r1a = vtrn2q_f32(row0a, row1a);
        r1b = vtrn2q_f32(row0b, row1b);
        r2a = vtrn1q_f32(row2a, row3a);
        r2b = vtrn1q_f32(row2b, row3b);
        r3a = vtrn2q_f32(row2a, row3a);
        r3b = vtrn2q_f32(row2b, row3b);
        r4a = vtrn1q_f32(row4a, row5a);
        r4b = vtrn1q_f32(row4b, row5b);
        r5a = vtrn2q_f32(row4a, row5a);
        r5b = vtrn2q_f32(row4b, row5b);
        r6a = vtrn1q_f32(row6a, row7a);
        r6b = vtrn1q_f32(row6b, row7b);
        r7a = vtrn2q_f32(row6a, row7a);
        r7b = vtrn2q_f32(row6b, row7b);

        row0a = vtrn1q_f64(row0a, row2a);
        row0b = vtrn1q_f64(row0b, row2b);
        row1a = vtrn1q_f64(row1a, row3a);
        row1b = vtrn1q_f64(row1b, row3b);
        row2a = vtrn2q_f64(row0a, row2a);
        row2b = vtrn2q_f64(row0b, row2b);
        row3a = vtrn2q_f64(row1a, row3a);
        row3b = vtrn2q_f64(row1b, row3b);
        row4a = vtrn1q_f64(row4a, row6a);
        row4b = vtrn1q_f64(row4b, row6b);
        row5a = vtrn1q_f64(row5a, row7a);
        row5b = vtrn1q_f64(row5b, row7b);
        row6a = vtrn2q_f64(row4a, row6a);
        row6b = vtrn2q_f64(row4b, row6b);
        row7a = vtrn2q_f64(row5a, row7a);
        row7b = vtrn2q_f64(row5b, row7b);

        vst1q_f32(pDst, row0a);
        pDst += 4;
        vst1q_f32(pDst, row4a);
        pDst += 4;
        vst1q_f32(pDst, row1a);
        pDst += 4;
        vst1q_f32(pDst, row5a);
        pDst += 4;
        vst1q_f32(pDst, row2a);
        pDst += 4;
        vst1q_f32(pDst, row6a);
        pDst += 4;
        vst1q_f32(pDst, row3a);
        pDst += 4;
        vst1q_f32(pDst, row7a);
        pDst += 4;
        vst1q_f32(pDst, row0b);
        pDst += 4;
        vst1q_f32(pDst, row4b);
        pDst += 4;
        vst1q_f32(pDst, row1b);
        pDst += 4;
        vst1q_f32(pDst, row5b);
        pDst += 4;
        vst1q_f32(pDst, row2b);
        pDst += 4;
        vst1q_f32(pDst, row6b);
        pDst += 4;
        vst1q_f32(pDst, row3b);
        pDst += 4;
        vst1q_f32(pDst, row7b);

    }
```

It boils down to : **16 load + 32 trn + 16 store vs 64 load + 64 store**

Now we can clearly see it really isn't worth it. The neon routine above might be a little faster, but I doubt it will make a difference in the end.

No, you can't optimize it any further. Nobody can. Just make sure the pointers are 64byte aligned, test it, and decide for yourself.

```
ld1     {v0.4s-v3.4s}, [x1], #64
ld1     {v4.4s-v7.4s}, [x1], #64
ld1     {v16.4s-v19.4s}, [x1], #64
ld1     {v20.4s-v23.4s}, [x1]

trn1    v24.4s, v0.4s, v2.4s    // row0
trn1    v25.4s, v1.4s, v3.4s
trn2    v26.4s, v0.4s, v2.4s    // row1
trn2    v27.4s, v1.4s, v3.4s
trn1    v28.4s, v4.4s, v6.4s    // row2
trn1    v29.4s, v5.4s, v7.4s
trn2    v30.4s, v4.4s, v6.4s    // row3
trn2    v31.4s, v5.4s, v7.4s
trn1    v0.4s, v16.4s, v18.4s   // row4
trn1    v1.4s, v17.4s, v19.4s
trn2    v2.4s, v16.4s, v18.4s   // row5
trn2    v3.4s, v17.4s, v19.4s
trn1    v4.4s, v20.4s, v22.4s   // row6
trn1    v5.4s, v21.4s, v23.4s
trn2    v6.4s, v20.4s, v22.4s   // row7
trn2    v7.4s, v21.4s, v23.4s

trn1    v16.2d, v24.2d, v28.2d  // row0a
trn1    v17.2d, v0.2d, v4.2d    // row0b
trn1    v18.2d, v26.2d, v30.2d  // row1a
trn1    v19.2d, v2.2d, v6.2d    // row1b
trn2    v20.2d, v24.2d, v28.2d  // row2a
trn2    v21.2d, v0.2d, v4.2d    // row2b
trn2    v22.2d, v26.2d, v30.2d  // row3a
trn2    v23.2d, v2.2d, v6.2d    // row3b

st1     {v16.4s-v19.4s}, [x0], #64
st1     {v20.4s-v23.4s}, [x0], #64

trn1    v16.2d, v25.2d, v29.2d  // row4a
trn1    v17.2d, v1.2d, v5.2d    // row4b
trn1    v18.2d, v27.2d, v31.2d  // row5a
trn1    v19.2d, v3.2d, v7.2d    // row5b
trn2    v20.2d, v25.2d, v29.2d  // row4a
trn2    v21.2d, v1.2d, v5.2d    // row4b
trn2    v22.2d, v27.2d, v31.2d  // row5a
trn2    v23.2d, v3.2d, v7.2d    // row5b

st1     {v16.4s-v19.4s}, [x0], #64
st1     {v20.4s-v23.4s}, [x0]

ret
```

above is the hand optimized assembly version that's most probably shorter (as short as it can get), but not exactly meaningfully faster than:

Below is the pure C version that I'd settle with:

```
void transpose8x8(float *pDst, float *pSrc)
{
    uint32_t i = 8;
    do {
        pDst[0] = *pSrc++;
        pDst[8] = *pSrc++;
        pDst[16] = *pSrc++;
        pDst[24] = *pSrc++;
        pDst[32] = *pSrc++;
        pDst[40] = *pSrc++;
        pDst[48] = *pSrc++;
        pDst[56] = *pSrc++;
        pDst++;            
    } while (--i);
}
```

or

```
void transpose8x8(float *pDst, float *pSrc)
{
    uint32_t i = 8;
    do {
        *pDst++ = pSrc[0];
        *pDst++ = pSrc[8];
        *pDst++ = pSrc[16];
        *pDst++ = pSrc[24];
        *pDst++ = pSrc[32];
        *pDst++ = pSrc[40];
        *pDst++ = pSrc[48];
        *pDst++ = pSrc[56];
        pSrc++;
    } while (--i);
}
```

PS: It could bring some gain in performance/power consumption if you declared `pDst` and `pSrc` `uint32_t *`, because the compiler would definitely generate pure integer machine code which has most various addressing modes, and only use `w` registers instead of `s` ones. Just typecase `float *` to `uint32_t *`

PS2: Clang already utilizes `w` registers instead of `s` ones while GCC is being GCC.... When will GNU-shills finally admit the fact that GCC is an extremely bad choice for ARM?
[godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/rz44q6zrM)

PS3: Below is the non-neon version in assembly (zero latency) since I was very disappointed (even shocked) in both Clang and GCC above:

```
    .arch armv8-a
    .global transpose8x8
    .text

.balign 64
.func
transpose8x8:
    mov     w10, #8
    sub     x0, x0, #8
.balign 16
1:
    ldr     w2, [x1, #0]
    ldr     w3, [x1, #32]
    ldr     w4, [x1, #64]
    ldr     w5, [x1, #96]
    ldr     w6, [x1, #128]
    ldr     w7, [x1, #160]
    ldr     w8, [x1, #192]
    ldr     w9, [x1, #224]
    subs    w10, w10, #1
    stp     w2, w3, [x0, #8]
    add     x1, x1, #4
    stp     w4, w5, [x0, #16]
    stp     w6, w7, [x0, #24]
    stp     w8, w9, [x0, #32]!
    b.ne    1b
.balign 16
    ret
.endfunc
.end
```

It's arguably the best version you will ever get if you still insist on doing pure 8x8 transpose. It might be a little slower than the neon assembly version, but consume considerably less power.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to optimise the 8x8 neon code presented in the other answer; 8x8 transpose can be not only thought of as recursive version of `[A B;C D]' == [A' C'; B' D']` but also as repeated application of zip or unzip.

```
  a b c d  
  e f g h 
  i j k l
  m n o p  == a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p

  zip(first_half, last_half) ==
  zip(...) == a i b j c k d l e m f n g o h p
  zip(...) == a e i m b f j n c g k o d h l p == transpose
```

For 8x8 matrix we need to apply this algorithm 3 times and reading the data by vld4 two of those passes have been already done.

```
   float32x4x4_t d0 = vld4q_f32(input);
   float32x4x4_t d1 = vld4q_f32(input + 16);
   float32x4x4_t d2 = vld4q_f32(input + 32);
   float32x4x4_t d3 = vld4q_f32(input + 48);
   float32x4x4_t e0 = {
       vzipq_f32(d0.val[0], d2.val[0]).val[0],
       vzipq_f32(d0.val[1], d2.val[1]).val[0],
       vzipq_f32(d0.val[2], d2.val[2]).val[0],
       vzipq_f32(d0.val[3], d2.val[3]).val[0]
   };
   float32x4x4_t e1 = {
       vzipq_f32(d1.val[0], d3.val[0]).val[0],
       vzipq_f32(d1.val[1], d3.val[1]).val[0],
       vzipq_f32(d1.val[2], d3.val[2]).val[0],
       vzipq_f32(d1.val[3], d3.val[3]).val[0]
   };
   float32x4x4_t e2 = {
       vzipq_f32(d0.val[0], d2.val[0]).val[1],
       vzipq_f32(d0.val[1], d2.val[1]).val[1],
       vzipq_f32(d0.val[2], d2.val[2]).val[1],
       vzipq_f32(d0.val[3], d2.val[3]).val[1]
   };
   float32x4x4_t e3 = {
       vzipq_f32(d1.val[0], d3.val[0]).val[1],
       vzipq_f32(d1.val[1], d3.val[1]).val[1],
       vzipq_f32(d1.val[2], d3.val[2]).val[1],
       vzipq_f32(d1.val[3], d3.val[3]).val[1]
   };
   vst1q_f32_x4(output, e0);
   vst1q_f32_x4(output + 16, e1);
   vst1q_f32_x4(output + 32, e2);
   vst1q_f32_x4(output + 48, e3);
```

One should be able to perform the transpose also by starting with `vld1q_f32_x4`, then `uzpq` and finish with `vst4q_f32`.